# The module does not dissapear after disable, uninstall, clear cache and cron job

Tags: 7, installation

I want to completely remove the `File entity`module from my Drupal site.

I've disabled the module via `Modules` in admin panal. Then I also uninstalled it though the panel. After that, I've deleted the files from ftp located under `/sites/all/modules/file_entity`.

I've cleared the cache. I've run the cron. I even tried `/update.php` but it says there's nothing to update `Review updates` step.

When I log into administration panel, I still see that ghost:
[image]

I don't have any module that is dependent on `File entity`.

How to remove that module? I want to do so I can install the new fresh version of it which I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module might live in a profile or in a directory that is not sites/all/modules. It is possible to have the same module in multiple places in Drupal at the same time.

You should open up the database, go to the `system` table and look for the entry for `file_entity` and see what the path is. That will tell you. You could also grep your codebase for "File entity" or "file_entity" which should also produce results.

If not, perhaps you are on a dev/stage environment? Did your FTP program actually delete the files? Check that there wasn't a permission issue regarding deleting that.

**edit: if this is an older release of the media module, it used to ship with file_entity under media/modules/file_entity if I recall. Also check there. If that is the case, what you should do is completely upgrade the media module to the latest version, which looks like rc2 right now.**

Comment: That was the case! The module was located under `/sites/all/modules` but also e.g. `/sites/all/modules/media`.

Comment: Okay, thats what I thought. Media module used to ship with that module included, and at some point it was removed. I couldn't find that in the git history at a quick glance, so I removed that part of my answer. I will restore it.